# Show only errors in Chrome development console

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Is there a way to display only errors on the Chrome development console?

Right now it displays about a million warnings and I have to search through them to find the errors.

Thanks!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In the latest version of Chrome console there is now a drop-down menu next to the Filter box, which is set to "Info" by default. This menu allows you to switch between only showing errors, warnings, info or verbose.

Pictured here:

[image: The "Level" drop-down menu in the Google Chrome console]

Comment: You now have to click on the filter (funnel) icon first, then you get the options to show only errors / warnings etc.

Comment: Extra: You can hold CTRL and click in order to select multiple filters at once.

Comment: This is no longer true as of chrome 58.

Comment: I wonder what the new `verbose only` means and what has happened to `debug`.

Comment: This answer is obsolete with the latest chrome version. However it is possible to sort by status by clicking on the column title.

Comment: mine is disabled. how to enable

Answer (score 14):

You can hold the Control button (Command on Mac) to select more than one filter, such as 'Error' and 'Info' but not 'Warn'.

Comment: You just made my day a lot better!

Comment: Sadly, Google, in all it's wisdom, has decided to remove this feature in Chrom 58

Answer (score 2):

Use the filter buttons in the bottom status bar ("All", "Errors", "Warnings", "Logs")

Answer (score 2):

There is an errors filter in the bottom toolbar of the console. See the screenshot.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools - Console]