# Hide autocomplete verbose logs in console

Tags: google-chrome

Is it possible to hide `[DOM] Input elements should have autocomplete attributes` messages inside chrome's console? I don't want to add autocomplete to inputs of my web app and now my console is overpopulated with verbose messages which aren't relevant to me.

[image]

**EDIT:** This question is not duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589018/show-only-errors-in-chrome-development-console), since I want to show everything, except autocomplete warnings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show only errors in Chrome development console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9589018/show-only-errors-in-chrome-development-console)

Comment: @JoshLee, no it's not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add autocomplete="foo" for each input and they'll all dissappear, for example:

```
<input id="client-address-info" type="text" maxlength="80" autocomplete="foo">
```

Comment: This is not an answer. What if you do not want to autocomplete a form field?

Comment: @Xatoo I can't believe you haven't faced a form that autocomplete wrong fields or without a format you defined before. For these cases, here's the solution.

Comment: @IgnacioAra joe Ignacio, como la partes con 1462 puntos. Se nota que aprendiste mucho en Isban

Comment: @Enrique siempre hubo clases